# How to Tag Retention Graph in Azure Application Insight Dashboard

Tags: azure, visualization, azure-application-insights

I have Created A Retention Graph for User in Application Insights, I want to pin the visualization on the Dashboard, How can I do it, since pinning the retention graph gives me a 2*2 or 1*1 tile, which is nothing but a link to The retention page, whereas what i want is the visualization on the Dashboard itself.

Confirmation if this is even possible or not would also be a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the best option to reproduce the retention chart is to checkout the existing template in workbooks.

1. Please look for the "N-Period Retention" workbook with in the usage workbooks.

[image]

2. After selecting the parameters and chart reflects to your requirement, click on edit.

[image]

3. You can click on the pin

[image]

4. You can pin a section to the dashboard.

[image]

Hope this information helps.